# Casting error, IO C program

Tags: c

Overall objective: Read arbitrary file into a buffer, copy buffer over to farray while removing null characters.

Error:

> Allocating memory for arrays (which is reuqired)

error msg:

> warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function
>   ‘malloc’ [enabled by default]   farray = (char *)
>   malloc(sizeof(char));

EDIT: #include ,  and all other obvious ones included

```
char *farray;
const char* sarray;

farray = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*120);
sarray = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*120);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include stdlib.h for the definition of `malloc`.

Comment: pls use comment section, not really an answer, pls observe error msg

Comment: stdlib.h was already included, and the size is actaully char*120, i ommited because isn't related to error. Please see error

Comment: My mistake, had a spelling error in my #include, thank you for your answer